# RSS wrong date in PHP

Tags: php, date, rss

I want to have the date format `j/n/Y` in my RSS.

e.g: `31/5/2011` display in the RSS file `05/07/2013 00:00:00`.

I am using
`date ( "j/n/Y" ,time() );`

(**I'm taking the date from DB**)

Comment: Oops, you forgot to post your code!

Comment: Nothing ... I have just date (e.g: 31/5/2011)

Answer (score 0):

How are you generating this time string. Is `strtotime()` involved in any stage in that process? That function, while handy in some situations, is at best "artificially stupid" and will mis-interpret a wide variety of dates as something completely different.

Comment: date ( "j/n/Y" ,time() ); (I'm taking the date from database)